# GUID and hash table - how to use them?

Tags: c++, c, hash, hashtable, guid

I have several GUIDs and I'd like to implement a hash table to quickly retrieve them. How would I do that?

If I treat the GUIDs as hash codes I need to do something like

```
index = GUID % prime_number_that_covers_all_GUID_bits
```

but I'm unsure if this is the right way to do it. How should I do to realize such a hash table?

Comment: C or C++? In C++ there's `std::unordered_map`

Comment: Why do you want to use a hash table? Just put them in an array or something.

Comment: @melpomene I need fast access, array is O(n). C or C++ isn't relevant so I may use std::unordered_map as well

Comment: That won't work, as the "prime that covers all GUID bits" is larger than the maximal GUID, and you are back at a simple table of booleans. You need to use a prime that is somewhat larger than the number of expected GUIDs (so your hash table doesn't grow too large)  and resolve collisions somehow. Or you could go for the other extreme, a bitmap (one bit for each possible GUID). Pick what is easier to program/understand (and allows for reasonable growth if required later, or at least encapsulate the whole thing so that it is easy to rip out and replace by another implementation if needed later).

Comment: @JohnnyPauling "array" is nothing. It's a data structure, not an algorithm. Accessing an array element is O(1). What are you talking about?

Comment: @melpomene I can't do something like array[GUID] because that would grow an insanely huge hash table!

Comment: @JohnnyPauling You're supposed to do something like `GUID = array[2]`. As in an array storing GUIDs.

Comment: All right, but then I'd need something to link between a GUID and its own index (GUID and 2 in your example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `std::unordered_map`, which takes a `Key` type (`GUID`) in your case, and a `Value` type, which could be some user info or program info (depending on your app). Storing is as simple as calling the member functions `insert()` or `emplace()` and looking up a stored value is done by calling `find()`.

The example below uses `std::string` as the underlying type for your keys, and implicitly `std::hash<std::string>` as the hash function. For other GUID types, you might need to roll your own hash function object and pass that as a template parameter to the hash table.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

typedef std::string GUID;

class UserInfo
{
public:
    UserInfo(bool b): is_genius_(b) {}
    bool is_genius() const { return is_genius_; }

private:
    bool is_genius_;
    // your stuff here
};

int main()
{
     std::unordered_map<GUID, UserInfo> table;      
     GUID x = "Johnny Pauling";

     // insert into table
     table.emplace(x, UserInfo(true));

     // lookup in table
     auto it = table.find(x);

     // if found, print it
     if (it != table.end())
         std::cout << std::boolalpha << it->second.is_genius();
}
```

Output on [LiveWorkSpace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3bMHbB%249)

Comment: sigh. random downvotes :( a small explanation on what could be improved here, would be nice...